# Blackberry Javaloader

Tags: blackberry

I have never been able to get the Desktop Manager to work correctly load an app on my device; however, I can use javaloader.exe to load an app (sort of).  It only loads the cod file, not the alx. Okay, I'm desperate so I'll take what I can get.  The problem is that after I use the javaloader.exe on any file name, I can never ever reinstall an app by that name on the phone - even if I delete the file that's already there.

When I use javaloader to load the file more than once, the loader **says** that it loaded the file, but it's not in the download folder. Is there a trick?

For reference:
Developing using eclipse with plug-in
Phone is a 9630 Tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .alx file is only used by tools and servers to determine what needs to be loaded onto a device; the .alx file itself is never loaded to the device.

Loading the file again with javaloader will replace the previous instance. The phone may need to be rebooted before it shows up.

Does it show in Options | Applications?

You could try as well bbsak or Master Control Panel, though misusing these tools can wreck your data. Careful!

If you have access to Linux, I also suggest trying out bjavaloader from [barry-tools](http://www.netdirect.ca/software/packages/barry)

Comment: Rebooting the phone works, tx.  I might be able to coax a Linux box from my employer.  And thanks for the extra info ref the alx file.

Comment: Usually after loading a COD using javaloader that replaces an existing COD of the same name, the device will automatically reboot.  I'm surprised it doesn't do this for you.

Comment: I notice that if I left the program running that the device reboots; otherwise, it just copies over it.

Comment: Also I notice that if I move the program to a different directory, say "my test apps" that even if i delete the app from that directory, when I download a new app, it doesn't go to my "normal" download area, but to the directory I moved the (deleted) program to.  That was a little confusing.

Comment: It will automatically reboot the device when necessary to deallocate the old resources. If a resource (be it code, images, etc) are still in use a reboot is necessary to use the new version of the app.